# Is it possible to bundle the Mono runtime on OS X (without using Xamarin)?

Tags: runtime, monodevelop, bundle, monomac, xamarin.mac

I want to bundle the Mono runtime with my OS X application, so that the users won't need to install an additional framework just to run my application.

When attempting to use MonoDevelop's automatic packaging feature, and checking "Include the Mono runtime in the application bundle", I'm getting told that I need Xamarin.Mac for this. Now, Xamarin has a pretty high price for a tiny company like mine, and I hope I won't have to purchase the entire Xamarin package just to bundle the runtime.

My guess is that there are other ways of doing it. I spesifically remember reading something about included frameworks and setting environment variables a while back, but I can't find it anymore. There are comments and hints on the internet, even here on SO, and the consensus seems to be that it is indeed possible, but I have yet to find a description of *how* to do it. Most answers seem to link to parts of the mono-project.com web page that are now gone, as it is moved into the Xamarin package, I suspect.

So, is there any non-Xamarin way of including the Mono runtime in my app bundle, to let users run it without installing Mono?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The mono runtime is dual licensed, GPLv2 and to Xamarin. With the GPL licensed version you have, you legally can't bundle the runtime (even if it's technically possible).
By buying Xamarin.Mac, you mostly buy the right to a GPL free version of the runtime, which you can embed in your app.

You can still develop and distribute an app with MonoMac, but your users will need to install mono (through an installer of some sort), and you won't be able to publish to the App Store.

See also [Where is the difference between Xamarin.Mac and Mono:OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890861/where-is-the-difference-between-xamarin-mac-and-monoosx)

Comment: The mono runtime available under the **GNU LGPL v2** which is more permissive than the GPL v2.

Comment: Stackoverflow myth. I've seen this in two answers now @TrustMe is correct

Answer (score 6):

I believe Stephane's answer is incomplete.  You can bundle the mono runtime as long as you provide the end user the ability to upgrade the mono runtime independent of you.  And you do not have to bundle the entire runtime, just the portions that your app needs.

Here is one older post that describes some of the steps:
http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Embedding-into-XCode-project-td1751644.html

Best of luck.